# How to disable Control Centre play/pause buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, media-player, avplayer, control-center

I'm using AV Player, to play some videos in my apps, But if I open Control Centre and try to play and pause the video, it is playing and pausing, But I don't want that feature. I want to disable this functionality.So for this, I did like this...

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *remoteCommandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
    remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.enabled = NO;
    remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.enabled = NO;
    remoteCommandCenter.previousTrackCommand.enabled = NO;
    remoteCommandCenter.nextTrackCommand.enabled = NO;
```

This didn't work, then

```
    MPRemoteCommandCenter *remoteCommandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
    remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.enabled = YES;
    [remoteCommandCenter.playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(test)];
    remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.enabled = YES;
    [remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(test)];
    remoteCommandCenter.previousTrackCommand.enabled = NO;
    remoteCommandCenter.nextTrackCommand.enabled = NO;

    - (void)test {

// Not doing anything
    }
```

Then Another way I tried,

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *remoteCommandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
    remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.enabled = NO;
    [remoteCommandCenter.playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(test)];
    remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.enabled = NO;
    [remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(test)];
    remoteCommandCenter.previousTrackCommand.enabled = NO;
    remoteCommandCenter.nextTrackCommand.enabled = NO;

    - (void)test {

// Not doing anything
    }
```

But there is no use..

If I put a breakpoint at test method that I added as a target, It is getting the callback but no use. Still, play and pause buttons are working

Is there any way to disable to these buttons, Am I doing it correctly or not ?

Comment: Do you found any solution?

Comment: No Karthikeyan..

Comment: Am also struggling in the same issue

Comment: iam also facing same issue.did you find solution?@Wills-In

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make new function for:

```
remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.enabled = NO;
[remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(test)];
```

i.e. pause something like this because application became crash.